# Debug="true" in .aspx file not showing source code VS

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the error:

> The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:
>
> 1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:
>
> ```
> <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
> ```
>
> or:
>
> 2. Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:
>
> ```
> <configuration>
>    <system.web>
>        <compilation debug="true"/>
>    </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```

I've gotten this error before and fixed it just fine by adding Debug="true" to the top of my .aspx file like so:

`<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" Title="Account Management" MasterPageFile="~/tell/TELLcases.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Account.aspx.cs" Inherits="tell_Account" %>`

But for some reason, even though I've added Debug=true, I am still getting this error instead of the source code. Is there a common reason this would happen, or is there another setting somewhere that I need to change?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand what you're wanting, but maybe you also need to explicitly set the [`customErrors` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your web.config file to `mode="off"`?

Comment: I believe the asker is under the impression that "Debug" will literally "debug" the program and resolve the errors. Unfortunately, that isn't the case. @user3688298 - You will still need to resolve the errors by researching and fixing the problems in your code. Providing more details may be helpful. Drop a breakpoint somewhere in your code, then step through line by line using F10. Note exactly which line causes the error.

Comment: I know DEBUG won't fix the errors, but it's not even showing the errors. It still tells me to add Debug=true even though I've already done that. CustomErrors mode is set to off in my web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Debug true just tells the runtime to load symbols (pdb files).  PDB files are only generated when the project is build against the Debug target platform.

Either

A:, you have the project set to release when you build and as such have no pdb files, or
B: your pdb files are not in the web apps bin folder.

Or you are trying to debug dlls/code you don't have the source of, in which case there are no pdb files.  To get around that you need .Net Reflector and it's Visual Studio Addon, it can generate PDB files for all the referenced assemblies in your solution.  It costs like 99$ though but has a free trial.